# Can't able to set value for nested object param

Tags: magento-1.9, array, object

Below one is my custom observer object, I need to get/set value of **processor**

```
object {
  ["_quality":protected]=> int(10) /* 1st quality param.*/
  ["_processor":protected]=>
    object(Varien_Image) {
      ["_adapter":protected]=>
        object(Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2) {
          ["_quality":protected]=>int(10) /*2nd quality param.*/
        }
    }
  }
```

**It works:**

> var_dump($object->getQuality());

**It does not work, it always return null**

> var_dump($object->getProcessor());

Any help would be appreciated.